# jquery-ui datepicker problem

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, datepicker

hey guys I have two divs- with id="form1" which is inline and the other with id="form2" which gets its content through ajax(where the div tag is mentioned on the same page).

```
<div id="form1">
 .
 .form content
 .
 .
</div>
<div id="form2"> //gets content dynamically
```

Now, I have used the following datepicker code-

```
    $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker,#datepicker1" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
});
```

Now, I have applied the datepicker id to a field in form1 and it works perfectly.
The problem is in the second form. The second form gets generated by loop and i have used the following logic to apply the id datepicker1 to it-

```
<? foreach ($list as $key => $value): ?>
    <? $dt='';
    if($key=='date_of_purchase'){

        $dt="datepicker1";
    }?>
        <tr><td><?= $key ?> :</td><td><input id="<?=$dt;?>" type="text" name='<?= $key ?>' size="25" value='<?php echo $value; ?>'/></td></tr>
    <? endforeach; ?>
```

Now, the id datepicker1 is getting applied perfectly to the required field but the jquery datepicker popup is not coming up as expected.

Whats the solution??

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using a div as a wrapper for form elements (<form> is nice)?

Comment: its just because of a certain structure issue. Anyways I am not using any form attributes, so it doesnt matter.

Comment: Does your loop generate more than one input with the `id="datepicker1"`?

Comment: nope it doesnt..i checked for that possibility..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#datepicker1").live("click",function() {
    $(this).datepicker({showOn:'focus',dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'}).focus();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

> id="form2" which gets its content through ajax

Well, there's your problem :)

The javascript code that adds the datepicker functionality is probably executed before the ajax event is finished. Try and loading the datepicker for the second form after it's content has loaded.

Comment: E.g., in the callback of your `jQuery.ajax`.

Comment: nope that didnt help...if it is of any help, i am using ui-dialog for the form2(which gets called upon clicking edit button). The site is coded in codeigniter...the form2 loop is in a different view file..

Answer (score 0):

The jquery function is only running once when the dom is first loaded. It doesn't refire when you load ajax content. The best way to fix this is to use the jquery delegate function attached to a parent element. Just give the inputs that you want to have a datepicker the class of 'datepicker' (or some other way to select them). Something like this.

```
$('#parentID').delegate('.datepicker', 'focus', function() {
    $(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
});
```

I'm assuming that 'parentID' is the ID of some parent element of both forms.

Comment: i am sure it would have worked too...just that i didnt want to specify a common parentid....